# Error when testing Azure B2C sample web app with Google Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm testing this sample application to authenticate using Azure B2C and Google as the authentication provider: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi and am getting this error:

Error.
We're having trouble signing you in.
Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.

[Error from web application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHv6L.png)

In Azure B2C I'm using a custom policy and have also tested it using a redirect to jwt.ms and it also returns the tenant ID as a part of the output claim:

[JWT returned from testing custom policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxZH4.png)

Not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to debug this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you have a look at the network trace in the browser developer tools to see what AAD B2C returned to your application?

Comment: Yes @JasSuri-MSFT, the id_token decoded shows that B2C is returning the right claims to the app including the tenant id

Comment: From debugging the app I found that it is erroring with this message: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Identity.Client Version 4.37.0.0. This is because the current version is 4.39.0.0 and that is what Visual Studio downloaded. I'm not a developer but is there a way to get Visual Studio to download the old version of MSAL and remove the newer version?